# How can I setup #Spark/#Kafka on Docker ?

Tags: apache-spark, docker, apache-kafka

I am trying to set up a Docker Machine to build an app and use Spark and Kafka. Do you have any idea how can I set up it on mac machine.

Comment: This post covers kafka and spark-streaming (which is what I assume you want if setting up with kafka):
http://blog.antlypls.com/blog/2015/10/05/getting-started-with-spark-streaming-using-docker/